# Downcast set of type X that are subclass of of Y

Tags: ios, swift, downcast

***Note***: although the question has a `CoreData` example, it's not related to `CoreData`, it's just an example

We are working on a Swift project with `CoreData` as a caching layer.

We make use of `Notification`s in our `mainViewController` a lot to listen to the changes after our `NSManagedObjectContext` has new changes.

This is working great until we added new entities with the following hierarchy:

- Entity `Vehicle` is a base class with some attributes.
- Entity `Car` is a subclass of `Vehicle` with specific attributes and a toMany relationship to `Human` entity.
- Entity `Human` is a base class with specific attributes, and it has a relationship the `Car`.

[image: Entities]

**The problem is in the following:**
when a new `Car` object is added, the notification fires, and in the `mainViewController`, we need to check if it's of type `Car`, like this:

```
if let insertedObjects = notification.userInfo?[NSInsertedObjectsKey] as? Set<Car> {
    print("we have some cars") // this will never execute
}
```

The type downcast `Set<Car>` will never evaluate to true because the `Set` has elements of type `Car` and also `Human`.

**What I want:**
Check if the `Set` has NSManagedObject subclass of type `Car` or `Human` as I downcast it.

**What I tried to do:**
downcast it to `NSManagedObject`, and check if the `Set` contains `Car` by the adding the following `where` condition:
`insertedObjects.contains(Car)`, but it has a compile-time error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Car).Type' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'
```

*Let me know if you have any question instead of just downvoting.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the type casting (I think I remember doing it the same way and it worked, although it was with an array), but checking if there is a car in the set is different:

```
set.contains { (element) -> Bool in
    return element is Car
}
```

Or shorter (more concise) version of the same call:

```
set.contains(where: { $0 is Car })
```

Answer (score 1):

First downcast the inserted object to `Set<NSManagedObject>`.
To check if any car has been inserted, use

```
if let insertedObjects = notification.userInfo?[NSInsertedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> {

    if insertedObjects.contains(where: { $0 is Car }) {
        print("we have some cars")
    }

}
```

To get the inserted car objects  as a (possibly empty) array, 
use `flatMap()`:

```
if let insertedObjects = notification.userInfo?[NSInsertedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> {

    let insertedCars = insertedObjects.flatMap { $0 as? Car }

}
```

---

Your approach

```
if insertedObjects.contains(Car)
```

does not compile because

```
func contains(_ member: Set.Element) -> Bool
```

expects an *instance* of the element type as argument.
As shown above, you can use the predicate-based variant

```
func contains(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

instead.